# What will electrician use to replace a decorative cover which is covering electric wires?

Tags: electrical, wiring

My condo apartment which I own has those electric baseboard heating units along the window [image: baseboard heating units]

The last one seemed to be decorative and it sticks out and blocks space we need to install a kitchen cabinet. [image: decorative segment]

So we popped the cover off and in fact it's *mostly* decorative, except for protecting the two wires inside [image: wire inside] which are coming out of the raceway behind it and going into the first actual heating unit.[image: other end of wires]

We will have electrician here for the actual work, but we're trying to figure out what slimmer or shorter cover they could use that's still a legit protection of the wires?  If we know the options in advance we can calculate clearance for the cabinet.

Comment: In an apartment I would not touch this myself.  You should contact the landlord, who will get an electrician in, to modify it.  Something goes wrong and they will take you for everything you have and more, and then get nasty.

Comment: Good luck getting that modified.  It's an apartment, so not your property  and the owner/manager will not spend on modifying something like a heating component to accommodate your furnishing desires. You are better served looking at how to arrange the cabinet to fit your needs.

Comment: @crip659 I am the landlord.  I own this condo so it is my property.  The decorative part is inside the unit. If it broke I would be responsible for fixing it.  I don’t know where you got the idea that I’m remodeling a rental.

Comment: @rmdman this is my property which is why I’m remodeling the kitchen.

Comment: Why not proceed with the disassembly? There appears to be a joint where the wires enter on the left, and a hex-headed fastener. What's to the right? All the protection the wires need is a slim conduit in otherwise exposed areas, which could likely be provided in a non-interfereing location.

Comment: Most places if they allow owners to work on electric will be only for single detach homes.  Any multi unit buildings need to use a licensed electrician.  If your condo is a single detach home you can go for it.

Comment: _This_ one unit is your property, but if you mess up the electrical work and start a fire, that will effect _other people's_ homes. Code is designed to protect against that. That's why you're getting the recommendations to call in a licensed electrician. The condo association & the insurance company have deep pockets full of lawyers who they will happily sick on you should something go wrong. Not saying you're going to screw it up, (but accidents _do_ happen), we're just trying to protect you and keep you within the law.